# Add Mutable Dictionary to a Mutable Dictionary for conversion to JSON

Tags: xcode, json, cocoa, embed, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to build a dictionary which has as dictionary within it (eventually I hope to convert to a JSON).  The problem is I am having problems building it.

So far I have this, what it should do is build a small dictionary with keys and add it to a larger dictionary, reset and then load the small dict and then add it to the large one.

```
NSMutableDictionary *nestedList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];   
NSMutableDictionary *nestedSections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];



[nestedList addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:46], @"menuHeight",
                                      @"editText", @"menuMethod",
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"menuOption",
                                      nil]];

[nestedSections addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          nestedList, "@Basic",

                                          nil]];
[nestedList removeAllObjects];

[nestedList addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:92], @"menuHeight",
                                      @"sendText", @"menuMethod",
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"menuOption",
                                      nil]];

[nestedSections addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          nestedList, "@Pro",

                                          nil]];
```

I then hoped to address like so;

```
NSString *string = [[nestedSections objectForKey:@"Pro"] objectForKey:@"menuMethod"];
NSLog(@"Method is : %@", string);
```

Log would hope to read **sendText**

The first dictionary builds fine but as soon as I try and add it to the second t bums out with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I think it is a memory addressing problem because they are both mutable but I am not sure, maybe nestedList should not be mutable.  Any help appreciated.

Ultimately I would like to convert this to a JSON like;

```
{
   "Basic":
     {
        "menuHeight":"46",
        "menuMethod":"editText",
        "menuOption":"1",
     },
   "Pro":
     {       
        "menuHeight":"96",
        "menuMethod":"sendText",
        "menuOption":"1",
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. `NSMutableDictionary` does not copy the values (only the keys). Therefore you add the same dictionary two times and change both (= the one) when removing objects and so on. Beside this in your sample JSON the numbers looks like strings not like numbers. I think, that this is a typo.

B. Adding modern Objective-C for better readability it should look like this:

```
NSDictionary *basicDictionary = 
@{
    @"menuHeight" : @46,
    @"menuMethod" : "editText",
    @"menuOption : @1
}

NSDictionary *proDictionary = 
@{
    @"menuHeight" : @96,
    @"menuMethod" : "sendText",
    @"menuOption : @1
}

NSDictionary *nestedSections = @{ @"Pro" : proDictionary, @"Basic" : basicDictionary };
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.  That reads much better too....  Yes typo on the JSON well spotted.